# Use SELF.PATH with the new Facebook URL return

Tags: python, flask

I use this code: https://github.com/andrewiggins/Facebook-Friend-Graph to get graph file from Facebook.

Actually, it has worked great for a long time. But all of the sudden, self path won't work anymore? It seems to me that self.path is empty.

Edit: Okay, after some research I have found out that Facebook actually has changed how they return a url.

They returned the url like : `http://xxxxxx:8000/?accesstoken=`

but now they have changed to: `http://xxxxxx:8000/?#accesstoken=`

Now self.path is not usable, because it dont understand the ?#

Any tips?

It fails in [accsesstoken.py](https://github.com/andrewiggins/Facebook-Friend-Graph/blob/master/src/2.7/accesstoken.py) , I get the following error:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [16/Oct/2013 11:21:36] "GET /? HTTP/1.1" 200 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Eskil/Downloads/Facebook-Friend-Graph-master/src/2.7/main.py", line 49, in main
    access_token = get_access_token(app_id)
  File "/Users/Eskil/Downloads/Facebook-Friend-Graph-master/src/2.7/accesstoken.py", line 122, in get_access_token
    raise Exception(httpd.error)
Exception: unknown error: {}
```

So the code where its failing is in accesstoken.py:

def do_GET(self):
    """This method extracts the access_token or error from the Facebook
    request after the user logs in or cancels the Facebook Authentication
    """
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
    self.end_headers()

```
self.server.access_token = ""
self.server.error = ""

if '?' in self.path:
    query = urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(self.path)[4])
    if query.has_key('access_token'):
        self.server.access_token = query['access_token'][0]
        self.wfile.write(html % ('Thank You!', 'You may now close this tab.'))
    else:
        self.server.error = query.get('error_reason', ['unknown error: %s' % str(query)])[0]
        if self.server.error == 'user_denied':
            self.wfile.write(html % ('Error', 'You must login to Facebook for the software to work.<br/>' +
                'This software does not store any user names or passwords.'))
        else:
            self.wfile.write(html % ('Error', 'Sorry! An error has occurred. Please try again.'))
else:
    self.wfile.write(html % ('Redirect', javascript_redirect))
```

The self path dont get the accesstoken from the URL, because all of the sudden theres a # in the url

Comment: Can you please modify your question and include a code sample of your code that is failing? Preferably a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It's very difficult when you specify links to entire code bases and say "I'm trying to use this".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it, changed from `if '?' in self.path`

to `if 'token' in self.path`

This way it goes to the last steep in the if else , and replaces # with ""

Also changed the javascrit on top to `window.location = url.replace("#", "")` , removes the #

Answer (score 0):

I guess that this code below might be a cause of the issue ([line 52 in accesstoken.py](https://github.com/andrewiggins/Facebook-Friend-Graph/blob/master/src/2.7/accesstoken.py#L52))

```
window.location = url.replace("#", "?")
```

I dont know anything about facebook graph but the above code means that every instance of '#' is replaced with '?' in the URL. So the URL now will become the following

```
http://whateversite:8000/??accesstoken= (notice the consecutive ??)
```

So it is creating a blank query string perhaps ?

Comment: Actually it doesnt.

See the if looP: 
if '?' in self.path: , if it doesnt find the ? THEN it replaces the # with ?